# Pandas. Selección por varios criterios utilizando máscaras

Tags: pandas

Intento realizar una selección múltiple, mediante máscaras, como se aprecia en el script siguiente.

```
mask1 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("ESP")
mask2 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("PRT")
mask3 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("GBR")
mask4 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("DEU")
mask5 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("ITA")
mask6 = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("FRA")
df_CEE = data[mask1&mask2&mask3&mask4&mask5&mask6] 
year_select = df_ESP['Year'] >= 2004
# seleccionamos todas las filas en las que el año es >= 2004, y las columnas cuys etiquetas invocamos.
df_aux_CEE = df_ESP.loc[year_select,["CountryCode", "IndicatorName","Year", "Value"] ]
df_aux_CEE.head(2)
```

Como resultado obtengo un dataframe vacío. 
Si solamente utilizo una máscara, me devuelve el dataframe correspondiente. ¿Cuál puede ser la razón?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que es como configuras la unión de las distintas máscaras. Al hacer:

```
df_CEE = data[mask1&mask2&mask3&mask4&mask5&mask6]
```

estas haciendo un `AND`, lo cual hace que cuando combines un máscara que sea `True, False` con otra que sea `False, True` el resultado debido al `AND` será `False, False`, por consiguiente el `Dataframe`final será vacío. Una solución en este caso es combinar las máscaras con un `OR`:

```
df_CEE = data[mask1|mask2|mask3|mask4|mask5|mask6]
```

Otra posibilidad es aprovechar que [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) permite expresiones regulares y hacer:

```
mask = data["CountryCode"].str.contains("ESP|PRT|GBR|DEU|ITA|FRA")
print(data[mask])
```